# How can I present a UIViewController modally showing presented Controller in the Blured Background?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

Having a `UIViewController1` and `UIViewController2` I want to present `UIViewController2` in `UIViewController1` modally. I can do this with:

```
self.presentViewController:animated:completion
```

What I want to do is present the `UIViewController2` such that it has size: 100x100 and is positioned in the center of the screen like a popup. When `UIViewController2` is present the surrounding of the `UIViewController2` should show some kind of glass layer where you can see the `UIViewController1` blurred.

How can I do that?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/, "A Look Inside Presentation Controllers"

Comment: i can suggest you on thing what you do just put one imageview in UIViewcontroller2 and make property of UIImage.
when you present the UIViewcontroller2 before that capture your UIViewcontroller1 and put blurred layer filter into it make UIImage object and assign it to property of UIImage in UIViewcontroller2. hope it will work for you. Blur filter you will get by googling.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate_protocol/index.html

Here is a tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/96062/custom-view-controller-presentation-transitions-swift

Answer (score 0):

Add UIView2 100x100 in UIViewController

.m

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *view2;
```

.h

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view2.hidden = YES;
}
```

Call view2 from button or code:

```
[self showView2];
```

And show it:

```
-(void) showView2
{
    self.view2.hidden = NO;


    self.view.opaque = NO;
    self.view.alpha = 0.5;
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.3 alpha:1];
}
```

Comment: I tried this but. The background gets darker with 0.5 not lighter?

Comment: play with self.view.alpha = 0.5, and replace self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.3 alpha:1]; with your color or backgroundImage

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the transitioningDelegate for UIViewController. You have a very good example, similar to what you want to achieve here:

https://github.com/schneiderandre/popping

Take a look at how CustomTransitionViewController is presenting using the PresentingAnimator class. You don't have to use POP Framework at for your animations, you can just animate the frame with the UIView class method:

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay usingSpringWithDamping:(CGFloat)dampingRatio initialSpringVelocity:(CGFloat)velocity options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
```

**Important**:you have to use UIModalPresentationCustom to have the presentingViewController visible behind the presented one.